# How to use TensorFlow python project in unity , then can build to iOS

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow

I have a python3.5 project that use Tensorflow, OpenCV, etc python library.

I want use this project in unity then use unity functions.

I have been searching some solutions, like IronPython,pythonnet,
But IronPython just support python2.7, pythonnet I can’t find some good example!

So I want reimplement python project in unity use TensorFlowSharp, but have too many functions need write in unity, seems difficult work need to do.

Whether have some simple solutions for this condition, I can easily use python project in unity, then build to ios。thanks.

Comment: i think there will be no "simple" solution. you can "compile" your Py Code to a pyc and than try to load it in c# as unsafe code. But keep in mind that you have to take care about memory leaks, pointers and even Unity itself will not be happy with this approach. this can lead to many problems. Unity will not with Iron Python.
you could also create an (WebApi) for your code and call your methods via http/RDP. Or you could create an executable file from your Py Code with params and use the return data. within c# just call the process. but this is also not a good way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have been rewriting part code use c#。